# how to search a word in xml file and print it in python

Tags: python, xml, nlp, nltk, tokenize

i want to search a specific word(which is entered by user) in .xml file. This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<words>
<entry>
<word>John</word>
<pron>()</pron>
<gram>[Noun]</gram>
<poem></poem>
<meanings>
<meaning>name</meaning>
</meanings>
</entry>
</words>
```

here is my Code

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


sen = input("Enter Your sentence - ")

print(sen)
print("\n")
print(word_tokenize(sen)[0])

tree = etree.parse('roman.xml')
node=etree.fromstring(tree)

#node=etree.fromstring('<a><word>waya</word><gram>[Noun]</gram> 
<meaning>talking</meaning></a>')
s = node.findtext(word_tokenize(sen)[0])
print(s)
```

i have tried everything but still its giving me error

> a bytes-like object is required, not 'ElementTree'

i really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're calling `etree.fromstring(tree)`, since in the previous line you've already parsed your source document into an `ElementTree` object. `tree` is not a string, and that's why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

the error happens because you are passing an elementtree object to the fromstring () methods. Do like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> a = etree.parse('a.xml')
>>> a
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x10fcabeb8>
>>> b = a.getroot()
>>> b
<Element 'words' at 0x10fb21f48>
>>> b[0][0].text
'John'
```

Use find() and findall() methods to search.

for more info, check lib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Simple example:

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<words>
  <word value="John"></word>
  <word value="Mike"></word>
  <word value="Scott"></word>
</words>
```

**example.py**

```
root = ET.parse("test.xml")
>>> search = root.findall(".//word/.[@value='John']")
>>> search
[<Element 'word' at 0x10be9c868>]
>>> search[0].attrib
{'value': 'John'}
>>> search[0].tag
'word'
```

Comment: I have modified my code, its working but i guess i'm doing something wrong in it. It isn't giving me the desired output. My xml file contains the first token name 'John' but still when my program searches for this it returns 'None'.

Comment: Here's my code
    import nltk from nltk.tokenize 
    import word_tokenize 
    import os 
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree 
    sen = input("Enter Your sentence - ") 
    print(sen) 
    print(word_tokenize(sen)) 
    print("\n") 
   print(word_tokenize(sen)[0]) 
   print("\n") 
   roman = etree.parse('roman.xml') 
   s = roman.findtext(word_tokenize(sen)[0]) print(s)

Comment: I updated the answer with a simple example. Check out this page, it will be useful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support. Hope this helps